# Solving complicated simulate equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am a PhD student in the field of wireless communications and networking engineering. There is a bible figure paper in the field, on which I am primarily relying on for my current part of dissertation research.

In the paper, there is a set of simultaneous equations given below
$$
\begin{equation}
\tau\left(p\right) = \frac{2(1-2p)}{(1-2p)(W+1)+pW(1-(2p)^m)}
\end{equation}
$$
and
$$
\begin{equation}
p = 1 - (1-\tau)^{n-1}
\end{equation}
$$
where $W$, $m$, and $n$ are constant natural numbers.

I am expecting that with a set of $(W,m,n)$, there can be something like a table of values of $\tau$ and $p$. The author stated in the paper, "It is easy to prove that this system has a unique solution," but didn't specify the solution and the numerical method of solving the equations.

I tried Wolfram Alpha on the Web and "solve" function in MATLAB to see neither worked.

Could you guys kindly help me solve this?

Comment: In your first equation, it looks like \tau is a function of p but in the second it looks like it is a scaler.  Please clarify.

Comment: Could you give some more background? What do the variables represent? What behavior does the system of equations model?

Comment: An example, with $(W,m,n)=(1,2,4)$ (chosen more or less at random), goes like this. f=@(p) 2\*(1-2\*p)/(2\*(1-2\*p)+1\*p\*(1-(2\*p)^2)); g=@(t) 1-(1-t)^3; h=@(t) f(g(t))-t; fsolve(h,1). It converges. All I did here was substitute in the expression for $p(\tau)$ into the equation for $\tau(p)$. This gives an equation which only involves $\tau$, which I tried to solve with Matlab's builtin fsolve. The actual function "solve" will usually fail because it will try to do it symbolically.